# C# Predicate.Target: get back urnderlying object

Tags: c#, delegates, predicate

Good morning.

Let me show you some code:

```
    //Db is a database of Tag objects, sort of
    Db db;   
    string code = "123";
    var selectedTag = db.Select(new Predicate<Tag>(tag => tag.Code == code));

    //...

    class Db
    {
        //A query method, accepting a Predicate
        public Tag Select(Predicate<Tag> predicate)
        {
            /* Here, using Intellisense, I see that Target property is a Tag object,
              but I can't cast it to Tag! Why??
            */
            var t = predicate.Target as Tag; //Always null!
        }
    }
```

I basically have a simple database of `Tag` object; when a caller invoke `Select` method, I would retirieve `Tag` object istance from `predicate`, but actually I can't get it work.
Using Intellisens in debug, when I am in `Select` method I clearly see that `predicate.Target` is referenced to my `Tag` object, but I don't know how to retrieve it.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

**EDIT**
If I try to unsafely cast `predicate.Target` to `Tag`, this way:

```
var t = (Tag)predicate.Target;
```

I get an `InvalidCastException`; ok, but `Exception` message says I cannot cast object of type `DbTests` to type `Tag`.
`DbTests` is the NUnit test class I'm using for my testing purpose (obviuosly...:).
Weird!
**EDIT 2**
Typo in line:

```
var selectedTag = db.Select(new Predicate<Tag>(tag => tag.Code == code));
```

Comment: sorry, just a typo, see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Select` method takes a delegate (the type of that delegate is a `Predicate<T>`, more specifically `Predicate<Tag>`).  that delegate points to an instance and a method.  What you've passed in for the delegate is a lambda `tag => tag.Code == code`.  That lambda causes the compiler to generate a method for this code.  That method is either contained on the instance that calls `Select`, or in a new class.    If the generated method is `static`, there will be no instance and `Target` will be `null`.  In any case that class that contains that method is not `Tag` (unless the call to `Select` is within the `Tag` class; but you didn't detail that).  So, `Target` cannot be a `Tag` object and can never be cast to `Tag` successfully.

The predicate that select receives should be *given* a `Tag` object.  For example:

```
public Tag Select(Predicate<Tag> predicate)
{
    Tag tag = new Tag();
    bool result = predicate(tag);
    return tag;
}
```

it's not clear what you really want to do within `Select`; but `Predicate<Tag>` just returns `true` or `false` depending on the `Tag` given to it.

#### Update:

In your example, it's as if you wrote this:

```
public class DbTests
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        Db db = new Db();
        Tag selectedTag = db.Select((Predicate<Tag>) TestTag);
    }

    private bool TestTag(Tag tag)
    {
        return tag.Code == "123";
    }
}
```

There is no `Tag` instance anywhere in the above snippet.

#### Update:

If you used an instance method from the containing class, for example:

```
public class DbTests
{
    public string code = "123";
    public void Test1()
    {
        Db db = new Db();
        Tag selectedTag = db.Select(tag => tag.Code == code);
    }
}
```

Then the predicate sent to select will have an instance associated with it and thus `Target` will not be null.  In the above code, `Target` would be of type `DbTest`  But, if you put the call to Select within `TagData` (e.g. `DbTests` was renamed to `TagData`) then `Target` would be of type `TagData` and show you instance members from `TagData` and you'd get what you see in your screen capture.

`Select` doesn't seem like the right term for a method that uses a `Predicate<T>`

Comment: My Db class is a simple wrapper around a persistence framework that query ojects using a Predicate. Now I want to substitute this framework, getting Tag object from Predicate and retrieving/storing it in another way, if possible. I want to get my job done in frictionless way, if I can. Obviuosly there are better ways to design code, I'm the first to admit that this is not a well done job :)

Comment: @FerdinandoSantacroce You can't get a `Tag` object from `Predicate<Tag>` because it is a delegate to a method that accepts a `Tag` argument.  e.g. `public bool DoSomethingWithTag(Tag tag)`

Comment: thank you, I got it now :). But why Intellisense can show it to me? I'm just curious.

Comment: @FerdinandoSantacroce When I debug that, intellisense is showing me `null` for `Target`

Comment: Take a look [debug screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/21l32id/6). My class here is named `TagData` instead of `Tag`.

Comment: @FerdinandoSantacroce In the code you posted, there where no instance variables used in the lambda passed to `Select` so the compiler generates a static method (Target is null).  If there were instance variables from the containing class used in the lambda then the compiler must generate a closure, in which case it has to generate an instance method so that Target is not null.  I've added more detail to the answer.

Comment: Well, I think there's no more to say. Thank you Peter for your time!

Answer (score 1):

`predicate.Target` is most likely not what you want.

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target.aspx) `Delegate.Target` "gets the class instance on which the current delegate invokes the instance method.". You say you are calling that code inside your unit test class `DbTests`, so that fit's perfectly.

Honestly, your complete code looks *wrong*. I think you don't want to have a `Select` method here but a `Where` method. A predicate inside a `Select` doesn't make too much sense, as a `Select` is simply a projection from one input value to one output value. Passing a predicate to such a projection means that the output value always is of type bool.

Comment: `Target` is definitely not what he wants.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Predicate<T> is just a short-hand for a function delegate that accepts a T and returns bool. So it's target is the instance which your predicate method belongs, in your case DBTests.

Comment: The compiler generates a static method for the lambda.  For example `<DbTests>b__0(Tag tag)`.  `Target` will always be `null`

Comment: @YiğitYener If it's correct, then the OP *can't be getting* `null` for `Target`.

Comment: Thank you for point me to `Delegate.Target` definiton, it was not clear to me before.

Comment: @Downvoter: Kindly explain your downvote so I may improve the answer.

Comment: @PeterRitchie He is not getting null. "I get an InvalidCastException; ok, but Exception message says I cannot cast object of type DbTests to type Tag."